# Move The First Div Appear Under the Second One in CSS

Tags: css

My html code looks like this:

A **wrapper div** (percent width, floated left) containing:

1. One div containing text and links;
2. One Div containing an image;

The problem:
I want to **keep the coding order like above**, but for user experience I want to inverse the divs order using CSS to get something like this:

*Note: the wrapper div is 20%, floated left, followed by 4 other similar divs on that page.*

[image: Inverse the order of the divs with CSS]

Ty!

This is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/4sbQf/

Comment: It would help if you would post your current code as well, if possible in a jsfiddle.

Comment: make the wrapper div relatively positioned... other two div's absolute positioned. image div with top:0px and text div with bottom:0px...

Comment: hello, i just attached a fiddle to the question, ty very much

Comment: Why can't you just swap the order in the HTML?

Comment: Do you know the height of your images?

Comment: No, everything is fluid, the website re-sizes it's resolution.

Comment: Thirtydot, for SEO purposes, google puts great value on the first link and I want it to be a text one, not an image one. Ty

Comment: You said that you don't know the height of your image and then you accepted an answer that relies on fixed and known image height. Weird.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only
this is better I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QGyNN/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="txt">
    </div>
    <div id="img">
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div#wrapper
{
    height:100px;
    width:60px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
div#txt, div#img
{
    position:absolute;
    margin: 5px;
    width:50px;
}
div#img
{
    top:0px;
    height: 60px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
div#txt
{
    bottom:0px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid green;
}​
```

Comment: All you need is a "float:left;" on your wrapper and you are good to go. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/4H8nc/3/

Comment: Hello, i tried this code and it should work, but maybe you can take a look at my site. It has adult content and I can paste it's name in the fiddle than delete it. Is that ok? Ty very much

Comment: On my actual site it seems to work but the wrapper now gets on top of everything. PS. On the actual site the wrapper div is inside another wrapper:)

Comment: Please take a look at this fiddle, i am somewhat of a newb. http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/4H8nc/4/

Comment: if your child element has floating property make sure the parent element also has floating property. see the http://jsfiddle.net/4H8nc/5/ If you remove `float` property from `#wrap` div it's height will be calculated as 0.

Comment: Ty very much for the help. I think the problem is my site is fluid and I do not have height for the text and images. Take a look, I have removed the height attributes from the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/4H8nc/6/

Comment: you will have to mention height; if not in CSS calculate using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/4H8nc/7/