# CSS - have div appear first in markup but display below floated divs

Tags: css, css-float

Any idea how to achieve the layout indicated in the image below with pure CSS, if the order of the divs in the markup must be as follows?

*NOTE - The height of each panel is unknown; wrapper divs may be added to the markup*

```
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="search-results"></div>
</body>
```

[image: Layout puzzle]

Comment: It's simple if the height of #content or the other divs is known as #content can be absolutely positioned and the other elements offset with padding/margin. But I'm otherwise completely stumped; I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: Here is a base jsfiddle of this problem if anyone wants to have a go: http://jsfiddle.net/kSsAB/

Comment: @3dgoo - you beat me to it :) thanks

Comment: No problem. Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414478/make-a-div-display-under-another-using-css-in-a-totally-fluid-layout

Comment: @3dgoo - thanks for the link. I'd almost decided it's not possible but thought there might be some obscure trick out there. Like that one!

Comment: I thought the same thing. There are some very clever people out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is taken from the question
[Make a div display under another using CSS in a totally fluid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414478/make-a-div-display-under-another-using-css-in-a-totally-fluid-layout).

It uses CSS table presentation using properties of display: table family to rearrange the presentation order of dom elements.

As said in the above question:

> This works in all modern browsers, and IE8 if you're careful. It does
>   not work in IE6/7.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-search-block">
        <div id="nav-wrapper">
            <div id="nav">nav</div>
        </div>
        <div id="search-results-wrapper">
            <div id="search-results">search-results</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```css
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav-wrapper, 
#search-results-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#nav, 
#search-results {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #6699ff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#nav-search-block {
    display: table-row-group;
}

#content-wrapper {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

#content {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #cc0000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kSsAB/2/)

Comment: Awesome. The only issue is that `display: table` is not supported by IE8 and below. Will hold out for a bit but will probably accept this one.

Comment: This is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) and does work in IE8. Just not in anything below. I'm keen to see if there is any other CSS only way of doing this too.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do this in javascript

as like this

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML=document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
display:none;
}


#one{
background:red;
    padding:10px;
    clear:both;
}
#nav{
background:green;
    float:left;
    width:35%;
}
#search-results{
float:right;
    width:65%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="content">Content I m first in html </div>
  <div id="nav">navi</div>
  <div id="search-results">Search-Results</div>

    <div id="one"></div>
</body>
```

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PQcqT/)***

Comment: Yeah I can do it with javascript but it feels 'dirty'. I'd asked if it's possible with pure CSS.