# How to switch css table-cell from left to right?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 types of layout, I'm just having trouble with the third. 
I used css based table for the 2nd layout with two columns because of its flexibility in terms of height. But I can't able to bring the left column to the right.

The html markup should be as is. Only selector is allowed.
Please help me play with it. thanks guys!

```css
body {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 80%
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.menu {
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px
}
.content {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px
}
/* table layout */

.wrapper.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table ul.menu,
.table .content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: none
}
.table ul.menu {
  width: 180px;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<h2>Original layout</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>New layout after adding the selector "table"</h2>
<div class="wrapper table">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Need help with this. (bring menu section to the right after adding the selector "right")</h2>
<div class="wrapper table">
  <ul class="menu right">
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g0x1o9bL/1/

Comment: I suppose you can't swap ul.menu and div.content's position in html right? also is jquery allowed?

Comment: why dont you use float:right in li tag

Comment: @Gereltod yup, can't manually swap it :) I have jquery to put the ul to the bottom, but since it is responsive, I want to return the layout back to layout format number one, then another problem arise for the third layout.

Comment: @Tanya, the ul should go to the right, not just the li :)

Comment: If jquery allowed I can easily do. But if not, i'm thinking about css :has selecter for catch it from parent level.s But its not working well currently. 
.table:has(ul.right) ul, .table:has(ul.right) div.content {
    float: right !important;
}

Comment: I appreciate your help, pls let's explore all the possibilities :)

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/g0x1o9bL/4/

Comment: Thanks @Super, but I can't add another markup on my layout.

Comment: @jamez88 can you use CSS flexbox? It is easy peasy that way.

Comment: @Salman, can we pls try that?

Comment: Please don't circumvent the quality filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rtl/ltr direction will do the trick :)

```css
body { width:70%;margin:10px auto; }

.wrapper { width:100% }
.wrapper ul.menu { background:orange }
.wrapper .content { background:gray;}

.wrapper.table { display:table;table-layout:fixed;}
.wrapper.table ul.menu,
.wrapper.table .content { display: table-cell; direction: ltr;}
.wrapper.table ul.menu { width:180px; }

.wrapper.table.right { direction: rtl; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper table">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper table right">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor labore et dolore magna Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again! this is a quick and easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in comment section, if jQuery is allowed this is working solution (maybe not best one, not sure)

```
$(function(){

    var elem = $("ul.right").parent("div.table");
    var ul_right = $("ul.right").remove();
    elem.append(ul_right);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/g0x1o9bL/5/

Comment: Thanks, but if jquery is the only solution, is there a way to return back the ul to its original position when the browser is for instance, 400px?

Comment: Of course, there is many way. For example if you using responsive css, if screen size lesser than 400px you can remove class itself. So jquery won't work there. Also on jquery code you can check element's or display's width, then decide do action or not. for example:  http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/g0x1o9bL/6/

Comment: I'm still thinking about pure css solution. but not working well.

Comment: Yup css solution should be better. By the way, I tried to resize the browser but the class isn't removed :)

Comment: above version haven't live handler. you have to refresh browser after change size on your browser. This one have listener for resize event:  
    http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/g0x1o9bL/7/

Comment: I did some research on css solution. It looks like you can't catch parent element from that .right class. so you have to put that class in <div class='wrapper table right'>. if it works for you there is some solutions:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only,  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css

Comment: "right" can go with main wrapper. Hope I can able to implement it. :)