# Push/Pull - Foundation

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

```
<dl>
    <dt class="small-12 medium-push-12 columns">Title</dt>
    <dd class="small-12 medium-pull-12 columns"><input type="text"></dd>
</dl>
```

On small screens I need title first then the text field, but on medium and up I need it the other way around - I've tried push and pull but they fail to work - any ideas?

Comment: You can't push/pull full width (12 wide) columns up or down. It would work if they were side-by-side on medium like this: http://codeply.com/go/g9SdeyJKl3

Answer (score -1):

According to [Swap DIV position with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only) (so it's a duplicate) you can try:

**html:**

```
<dl>
    <dt class="small-12 columns">Title</dt>
    <dd class="small-12 columns"><input type="text" /></dd>
</dl>
```

**scss:**

```
@media #{$medium-up} { 
    dl {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        dt { order: 2; }
        dd { order: 1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of your link. It says Foundation IN THE TITLE.