# Angular2 switch div content

Tags: angular, binding, ionic2

I am wanting to switch the content of two div in angular2/ionic2 this is my code. It does switch the html but I seem to loose all binding to the elements.

```
<ion-list>
<div #currencyFromHtml>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-8>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="currencyFromAmount" (ionChange)="refreshConversion()"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="currencyFrom"  (ionChange)="refreshConversion()">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let c of coins; let i = index" [selected]="i==0" [value]="c">{{c.title}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
<ion-row>
        <button ion-button (click)="switchToAndFromCurrency()">Switch</button>
  </ion-row>
<div #currencyToHtml>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-8>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="currencyToAmount"  (ionChange)="refreshConversion()"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="currencyTo" (ionChange)="refreshConversion()">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let cur of currency; let i = index" [selected]="i==0" [value]="cur">{{cur.title}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

The code that runs is this:

```
    switchToAndFromCurrency()
  {

console.log(this.currencyToHtml.nativeElement.innerHTML);

  let toHtml = this.currencyToHtml.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  let fromHtml = this.currencyFromHtml.nativeElement.innerHTML;

  this.currencyToHtml.nativeElement.innerHTML = fromHtml;
  this.currencyFromHtml.nativeElement.innerHTML = toHtml;
  }
```

This does the switch but I lose all the values on the page and the select elements dont work anymore.

Comment: What is the pupose behind this , so we can suggest better way of doing , as it dont looks good way of doing

Comment: well yeah..that's what's supposed to happen when you replace the html.

Comment: All I want to do is switch the top currency div with the bottom and keep all the functions working.
500 - ZAR top div
10- USD bottom div
I just want to move the bottom div to the top on a button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an `ng-template` for each inner content, and insert each one in an `ng-container` with `ngTemplateOutlet`. When appropriate, you would swap the templates of the two containers. The idea is shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5w831).

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
<ng-template #currencyFrom>
  <ion-row>
    currencyFrom stuff here...
  </ion-row>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #currencyTo>
  <ion-row>
    currencyTo stuff here...
  </ion-row>
</ng-template>
<div>
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="topTemplate"></ng-container>
</div>
<div>
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="bottomTemplate"></ng-container>
</div>
```

with the component code:

```
@ViewChild("currencyFrom") currencyFrom: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild("currencyTo") currencyTo: TemplateRef<any>;

topTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
bottomTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.topTemplate = this.currencyFrom;
  this.bottomTemplate = this.currencyTo;
}

switchToAndFromCurrency(): void {
  let temp = this.topTemplate;
  this.topTemplate = this.bottomTemplate;
  this.bottomTemplate = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can use css for this
[Swap DIV position with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only)

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```