# How can i make div 1 appear below in div 2 using css

Tags: css

```
<div class="1">
<p> THIS IS DIV 1> </p>
<div class="2">
<p> THIS IS DIV 2> </p>
```

I am using some shortcode but the problem is it will appear always on the top of all elements.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please show some more code. Your current code is totally invalid because your `div`'s aren't closed

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only) This might help..

Comment: please consider sorry mybad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex order. You'll have to add a container or use the current containing element and give it a `display: flex` property.

```css
.cont{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c1{
  order: 2;
}

.c2{
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="c1">
    <p> THIS IS DIV 1> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="c2">
    <p> THIS IS DIV 2> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: smooothh thanks! it works! simple coding!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your elements does not get closed properly. So assuming you fix it with this code:

```
<div class="class1">
    <p> THIS IS DIV 1> </p>
</div>
<div class="class2">
    <p> THIS IS DIV 2> </p>
</div>
```

Use `float: right;` and they will switch places. Or use flex display.

```css
.float {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.float .class {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.float:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="float">
    <div class="class class1">
        <p> THIS IS DIV 1> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="class class2">
        <p> THIS IS DIV 2> </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
    <div class="class class1">
        <p> THIS IS DIV 1> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="class class2">
        <p> THIS IS DIV 2> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution

The HTML:

```
<div class="one">
   <p></p>
</div>
<div class= "two">
   <p></p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
}

div.one {
  background: green;
}

div.two {
  background: red;
}
```

Please note that I changed the class name because CSS identifiers may not start with numbers. In CSS, class names used in selectors are considered "CSS identifiers". Therefore, the leading number must be escaped. If you really need to use numbers, then please refer to  [CSS escaping rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#escaping)

Answer (score -2):

Well first you would need to close the div with class 1 and the second one also.

```
<div class="1">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class= "2">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

try this and tell me what you get :)

YOu can also add css like this :

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Another and maybe the best way would be to make the second div float right .. like his :

```
.2 {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: But `1` will not be below `2`

Comment: @Justinas Yeah my bad .. I corrected it :)

Comment: Or he can just use flex or float but as simple as his code is .. i don't think he needs it

Comment: since I'm using wordpress and installing some plugins so i don't know which file to edit instead using css.. btw thanks for the help guys. already solved it!

Comment: How does floating the div right put it above the previous div?