# Responsive Slider with Image Position Changing

Tags: html, css, slider

At the moment I'm trying to make a responsive slider with text on the left and an image on the right.

On smaller screen, the image should move above the text (see below).

I have already tried this on a few occasions (for example with a grid or two images), but it did not work.

**Mobile:**

[image]

**Desktop:**

[image]

(Image source for the example: https://guten-tag.cmsmasters.net/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Hi Chris, you mentioned you had some examples that didn't work. Could you include them in your post?

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your feedback, and correct, some code I should have actually mentioned. Nevertheless, I have found a solution to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only) . Thanks for your time anyway ;D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Hi, thanks again for your feedback, and correct, some code I should have actually mentioned. Nevertheless, I have found a solution to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only). Thanks for your time anyway ;D